# Passing data from the controller to the view in a select dropdown on the view

Tags: php

I am having issues trying to get the data to pass to the view for drop-down and the data for the records also I am little lost on where everything goes. I started the concept and am trying to build from there any help would be appreciated. Trying to get the data from fetchall and getallemployees passed to the view edit page

controller partial code:

```
public function edit($Id)
    {
        require './server_url.php';
        if ($_POST) {
            $this->adminModel->update($Id);
            header("Location:  $server_url/index.php/admin");
        } else {
            $buildingArray = $this->adminModel->fetchData();
            $employee = $this->adminModel->getEmployeeById($Id,array('buildingResult' => $buildingArray));


    }
            require 'view/admin/form.php';
        }
```

model partial code

```
public function getAllEmployees()
    {
        $link = $this->db->openDbConnection();

        $result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM us_phone_list_table ORDER BY Id');

        $employee = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $employee[] = $row;
        }
        $this->db->closeDbConnection($link);


        return $employee;
    }
    public function getEmployeeById($Id)
    {
        $link = $this->db->openDbConnection();

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM us_phone_list_table WHERE  Id=:Id';
        $statement = $link->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();

        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->db->closeDbConnection($link);

        return $row;
    }

    function fetchData(){
        $selectBuilding = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * from building_table" );
        $selectBuilding->execute();
        $buildingResult = $selectBuilding->fetchAll();
        return $buildingResult;  
    }
```

view partial code:

```
 <select>
    <option value="">--- Select Building---</option>
      <?php
            foreach($buildingResult as $row){
              echo '<option value="'.$row['building_name'].'">'.$row['building_name'].'</option>';
            }
       ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Security hint: after `header("Location: ...)` always use `exit()` to stop PHP working after the redirect as you should not trust a HTTP client to respect and follow that redirect ... Meaning a HTTP client which does not follow that redirect can see things after the redirect or "run" PHP code after which should not be allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it should work. I just used the same concept as your getAllEmployees Function for fetchAll.

Controller

```
public function edit($Id)
            {
                require './server_url.php';
                if ($_POST) {
                    $this->adminModel->update($Id);
                    header("Location:  $server_url/index.php/admin");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $building = $this->adminModel->fetchData($Id);
                    $employee = $this->adminModel->getEmployeeById($Id);


            }
                    require 'view/admin/form.php';
                }
```

Model

```
function fetchData(){
        {
            $link = $this->db->openDbConnection();

            $result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM building_table ORDER BY Id');

            $building = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $building[] = $row;
            }
            $this->db->closeDbConnection($link);


            return $building;
        }
    }
```

View

```
<select>
    <option value="">--- Select Building---</option>
      <?php
            foreach($building as $row){
              echo '<option value="'.$row['building_name'].'">'.$row['building_name'].'</option>';
            }
       ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Just had to change view little to get it to insert.